# MVC - Is it a habit to have both Controller and Model in same class

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have a simple question, Is it good practice to add both controller and model in same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it good practice to add both controller and model in same class?

No, this is a very bad idea. One key to decent MVC is to make the model as view-agnostic as possible, so that it can be used by many different views, and since the control is usually tightly connected to the view, combining model and control will couple the model to the view, breaking MVC. On the other hand, combining view and control sometimes is done, especially with very small projects.

Comment: @MohanRaj: this is all well explained in any MVC tutorial, and I urge you to search for one or several and study them.

Comment: Actually i want to voted on your answer, but Stack Overflow doesnt allow me to do so.